# How to access parent viewmodel array in child class in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a viewmodel which consists an observablearray of items. I have a child class which is used in viewmodel. Can we access the observablearray from viewmodel in child class?

Here is my viewmodel and child class

```
function XeroxSection() {
  var self = this;
  self.xrxcostupliftdesc = ko.observable('This is some data');
  self.xrxdisticostgmdesc = ko.observable('This is some data');
  self.xrxothercost1 = ko.observable('This is some data');
  self.xrxothercost2 = ko.observable('This is some data');
  self.xrxcostuplift = ko.observable(5);
  self.xrxGM = ko.observable(10);
  self.Sum = ko.computed(function () {
    return 200;
  });
}
function Configuration(data,xrxsec) {
var self = this;
self.configKey = data.pKey;
self.configName = data.configName;
self.configNumber = data.modelnumber;
self.configMTP = ko.observable(data.mTP);
self.configMDP = ko.observable(data.mDP);
self.confxrxcostuplift = ko.computed(function () {
    return (self.configMTP() * xrxsec.xrxcostuplift()) / 100;
});
}
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.xrxSec = ko.observable(new XeroxSection());
  self.Configurations = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Configurations.push(new Configuration({configName:
  "PHASER 3010V/B PRINTER",mDP:10,mTP:20,pKey:1,modelNumber:"3010V_B"},
  self.xrxSec()));
  self.Configurations.push(new Configuration({
  configName:"PHASER 4015V/B PRINTER",mDP:90,mTP:50,pKey:2,modelNumber:"3010V_B"},
  self.xrxSec()));
  self.selConfig = ko.observable();
}
 var vm = new AppViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

As you can see from the above code i want to get the sum of configMTP of all configurations into computed observable "Sum" in XeroxSection class. Can someone help on how this can be achieved?

Here is the JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/XMYPb/

Answer (score 4):

When you are creating a child model send parent as parameter in child

```
self.ChildProperty(new childprop (params,self))
```

This way you will be able to access parent like this in child

```
var childprop = function(params , parent){
    var self = this
    self.Parent = ko.observable(parent)
}
```

Now you can access

```
self.Parent().Prop() // Prop is parent property
```